# In_array with spaces and adding results to same column PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a form that has check boxes and if the selection was not there, they can add text in into a text field `other:`.

To make it easier to find the `other:` I am trying to concatenate it with the text input.

```
$torsList = array('Bi-monthly','Quarterly','Monthly','Seasonal (Mosquito)','One Time ($1 6 month)','Specialty','Free inspection');

function addOther($input)
{
    if(in_array($input, $torsList)) {
        return $input;

    } else {
        return 'Other:'.$input;

    }
};
```

I believe the spaces are what are making a false statement when they select an item from the array.

if agent selects seasonal  (mosutio) then database column 1 will show `seasonal (mosquito)`
if agent inputs text then database column 1 will display `Other:what ever`

Ps: new to php

**Edit**

```
<label class="description" for="element_15" >Type of Recurring Service:</label>
<span>
    <input id="element_15_1" name="element_15" class="element radio" type="checkbox" value="Bi-monthly" />
    <label class="choice" for="element_15_1">Bi-monthly</label>
    <input id="element_15_2" name="element_15" class="element radio" type="checkbox" value="Quarterly" />
    <label class="choice" for="element_15_2">Quarterly</label>
    <input id="element_15_3" name="element_15" class="element radio" type="checkbox" value="Monthly" />
    <label class="choice" for="element_15_3">Monthly</label>
    <input id="element_15_4" name="element_15" class="element radio" type="checkbox" value="Seasonal (Mosquito)" />
    <label class="choice" for="element_15_4">Seasonal (Mosquito)</label>
    <input id="element_15_5" name="element_15" class="element radio" type="checkbox" value="One Time ($1 6 month)" />
    <label class="choice" for="element_15_5">One Time ($1 6 month)</label>
    <input id="element_15_6" name="element_15" class="element radio" type="checkbox" value="Specialty" />
    <label class="choice" for="element_15_6">Specialty</label>
    <input id="element_15_7" name="element_15" class="element radio" type="checkbox" value="Free inspection" />
    <label class="choice" for="element_15_7">Free inspection</label>
    Other:<input id="element_15_8" name="element_15_1" class="element text"       
type="text" />
</span>
```

This is how I'm using the function `$TypeOfRecurringService = addOther($_POST['element_15']);`

Comment: Why do you have different number of spaces in the array than in the checkbox values?

Comment: sorry typo (Only one space)

Comment: Then I don't understand the question. Spaces shouldn't cause `in_array()` to fail, if the spaces are the same in `$input` as they are in the array.

Comment: ok will look if my spaces are correct, because i get `Other:Seasonal (mosquito)` not `Seasonal (mosquito)`

Comment: It's not the spaces, it's `m` versus `M`. String equality is case-sensitive.

Comment: yes, i see, how can i make this work. take away the caps then.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but why are you using checkboxes when it looks like you need radio buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a variable scope problem. You defined the variable `$torsList` outside the function, but you're using it inside the function. If you turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL)`, you'll see that you're getting a warning about an undefined variable.

You need to put the `$torsList` variable inside the `addOther` function.

Comment: They look the same, I might be over looking

Comment: I'm at a loss. I can't explain why `$input = "Seasonal (mosquito)"` when your checkbox has `value="Seasonal (Mosquito)"`

Comment: sorry typo "Other:Seasonal (Mosquito)" is what is showing in my database

Comment: `$TypeOfRecurringService = addOther($_POST['element_15']);` is how im using the function